# string index out of range (while function)

Tags: python

при попытке вывести последнюю строку из списка по индексу получаю ошибку:

```
File "c:\path_to_file\count.py", line 9, in <module>
    fd = fd[x-1]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

код:

```
with open('separated.txt', 'r') as info:
    for line in info:
        fd = info.readlines()
        x = len(fd)
        print(x + 1)
        fd = fd[x-1]
        print(fd)
        while x !=1:
            fd = fd[x-1]
            print(fd)
```

Comment: `line 10` это `print(fd)`

Comment: @n1tr0xs а, да, спасибо, я просто убирал комментарий, а ошибку не изменил, спасибо

Comment: а задача то какая? Прочитать файл и отобразить последнюю строку в нем?

Comment: @ZxNuClear посчитать кол-во строк (переменная x) и вывести эти строки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот такой подход в корне неверный

```
for line in info:
    fd = info.readlines()
```

Во-первых, так вы сразу же пропускаете первую строку файла. Во-вторых, на второй итерации этого цикла (и последующих тоже) в переменной `fd` будет пустой список.
Вам нужно выбрать какой-то один из этих подходов.
С вашей задачей такой код должен помочь:

```
with open('D:\\Errors.txt', 'r') as info:
    lines = info.readlines()

print(len(lines))
for line in lines:
    print(line, end='')
```

Comment: насчёт первой строки я понял, в начале txt  файла на первой строке поставил пробел, а по поводу остального спасибо